# Admob ad not showing due to not having enough space

Tags: android, admob, ads, dimensions

I have implemented Admob ads in a project of mine. I'm using the latest version of Eclipse; Juno Service Release 1, with the latest updates. When I updated, I noticed that there are automatic additions to xml layout files; the @dimension/ references, like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...
   ...
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   ...
   ...
```

When I run the app on my Nexus 7,  the ads do not show, and I get an error that says the ad does not have enough space to show. After messing around with this, I found that if I remove  the @dimension/ references, the error goes away, and the ad appears. I don't want to have to go back to all my layout files to remove the @dimension/ references, so I'm asking for help in identifying a way around this problem. There has to be a way to make the ad work without deleting the @dimension/ references; is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

from your relative layout and problem is solved

Answer (score 3):

Another way to effectively do this is just go into `dimens.xml` and set the left and right padding to 0. That is, if you don't want the padding in any of your activities.

You're probably using `SMART_BANNER` AdSize, which unfortunately expects the entire screen (without padding), so there isn't a better way around this.